# cannot post to an angular2 'path/to/page'

Tags: angular, redirect, httpserver, openid-connect

I have an angular2 app with OIDC authentication (implicit flow). The external auth server redirects to angular2 application with http post request but the anuglar app is not handling it. I am able to view the contents of the same page with HTTP GET request when I fire that same page on browser. what am I missing here?

to reiterate:
Upon redirection from external server, I get a 404 error message and browser shows : "cannot post 'path/to/page'" while I can navigate to that page via browser.

Here are the scripts from the package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --disable-host-check",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:upgrade": "tsc",
    "serve:upgrade": "http-server",
    "build:aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js",
    "serve:aot": "lite-server -c bs-config.aot.json",
    "build:babel": "babel src -d src --extensions \".es6\" --source-maps",
    "copy-dist-files": "node ./copy-dist-files.js",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "ng": "ng",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: The question doesn't have much to do with angular. Your **server** receives a POST request to path/to/page. So it's a server issue: it needs to correctly handle a POST to that URL.

Comment: Thats true. I figured it too. It has to be something to do with my http development server. I am using ng serve.

** NG Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:80, open your browser on http://localhost:80/ **

Is there a way to enable handling POST requests on this.